# Video not showing in iPhone

Tags: video, video-streaming, android-videoview

My code is like that

```
<video style="width: 100%;" controlsList="nodownload" controls id="video-ytd10K" class="video-js" data-setup="{}" playsinline webkit-playsinline>       
   <source src="<?= $vid->get_temp_url($video_data->id); ?>" type="video/mp4" style="width: 100%;">
   Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Here I use temp URL for video.

In deskop or Android everyone can watch video but iPhone user cannot watch

And when I use main URL of the video. Video can be watched also in iPhone

I expect that video can be watch in iPhone by temp URL